# C# Create Chart with 2 YValues

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create in Visual Studio a chart with 1 XValue and 2 YValues (ChartType = Range).
How can I bind data (e.g. a dictionary) to this chart?

For all the other  charts (with only 1 YValue) I used succesfully the following code to bind a whole dictionary to the chart:

```
Dictionary<int, int> Dictionary1;
...
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(Dictionary1.Keys, Dictionary1.Values);
```

I tried to bind a a List to the YValues but that didn't work (Runtime error: Only the following types are possible Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort):

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> Dictionary2;
...
chart2.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindXY(Dictionary2.Keys, Dictionary2.Values);
```

Thanks, Luke

Comment: how can you relate one X value with LIST of Y values ??

Comment: I want to show a "Range" chart, i.e. a "Min Y Value" and a "Max Y Value" value vor the same X Value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the two y-values comma separated:

```
chart2.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Range;
int[] y1 = Dictionary2.Values.Select(y => y[0]).ToArray();
int[] y2 = Dictionary2.Values.Select(y => y[1]).ToArray();
chart2.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindXY(Dictionary2.Keys, y1, y2);
```

It is important to set the ChartType before as the number of possible y-values depends on it.

Comment: I'm new here, so I am unfortuantely not allowed to rate your answer up. Maybe somebody else can do that for me!?

Comment: Don't mind. I got points for the accepted answer. It wasn't sooo brilliant to be worthy to be upvoted. :-)

Comment: after a couple of hours searching for an answer I found yours as the perfect match for my solution. Thanks!